# Is it possible to use setup_method with fixtures?

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I have the following code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def example_smtp():
    return "example"

class TestClass(object):
    def test_function(self, example_smtp):
        # 1
        obj = NewObject(example_smtp)
        obj.initialize()

        print example_smtp
        # here may rise exception
        some_action()

        # 2
        # but we have to cleanup
        obj.cleanup()
```

some_action() may raise a exception, so I want to move 1 and 2 to setup_method and teardown_method, but I don't know how to do it.
setup_method allows only two arguments, so I can't use example_smtp in it.

Comment: Why not use a [`yield` fixture](http://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html#yieldfixture)? This keeps the setup and teardown for the fixture separate.

Comment: yield fixture is not what i'm looking for, but I used request.addfinalizer()
take a look http://pastebin.com/Y9L1A5Rh

Comment: Then write your own answer, rather than sending people to pastebin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to just write a fixture that creates `NewObject` for you and cleans up afterwards:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def example_smtp():
    return "example"

class TestClass(object):

    @pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True)
    def obj(self):
        obj = NewObject(example_smtp)
        obj.initialize()
        yield obj
        obj.cleanup()            

    def test_function(self, obj, example_smtp):
        # use obj here
        some_action(obj)
```

But if you **really** prefer to have a "setup_method"-like function (perhaps you are initializing several objects which don't appear in your snippet), you can declare an `autouse` fixture instead:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def example_smtp():
    return "example"

class TestClass(object):

    @pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True)
    def some_setup(self):
        self.obj = ...
        # ... setup other objects, perhaps
        yield 
        # ... cleanup everything
        self.obj.cleanup()

    def test_function(self, example_smtp):
        some_action(self.obj)
```

IMO, there's no compelling reason **not** to use fixtures when using pytest style test classes (IOW, not subclassing `unittest.TestCase`) because if you want a single method that does all the setup/cleanup for you you can use an `autouse` fixture.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem with addfinalizer() function from request object.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def example_smtp():
        return "example"

class TestClass(object):
        @pytest.fixture
        def obj(self, request, example_smtp):
                print 'initialize', example_smtp

                def fin():
                        print 'finalize'
                request.addfinalizer(fin)

        def test(self, obj):
                some_action_raise_error()
```

Thank you jonrsharpe for information about yield fixtures.

Comment: That's a *really* odd way to implement it - normally you'd do so in the original fixture, not when you use it in the test class. See e.g. https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code